# convert contents in DataFrame to txt file

Tags: python

I just ask somethings~ I wanna make Word Cloud. so I extracted my data from mysql using pymysql. My script like below

```
import sys
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='secret',
                   db='first_day', charset='utf8')
curs = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
sql = "select * from first_day_datas"
curs.execute(sql)
rows = curs.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(df.head())
df = df[pd.notnull(df['longitude'])]
print(df.head())
```

and my data status like below picture
[image]

I alreay got rid of the rows in which doesn't contain longtitude value.
Here is my question. How can I convert 'blogtext' column to .txt file??
I will make wordcloud using wordcloud libarary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you want line by line format for each row

```
with open('/tmp/data.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in map(str, df.head()['blogtext']):
        f.write(row + "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`Series.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html), also it seem you need omit first `index` column:

```
df['blogtext'].to_csv('myfile.txt',index=False)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'blogtext':['a','s','d'],
                   'address':['o','i','r']})
print (df)
  address blogtext
0       o        a
1       i        s
2       r        d

print (df['blogtext'].to_csv(index=False))
a
s
d
```

---

```
print (df['blogtext'].to_csv())
0,a
1,s
2,d
```